# Select and put points onto lines on QGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I just started QGIS in my work-study program this year and I don't understand something. I built 2 layers: one with points and the other with lines. I would like to put each point on the lines with snapping but, at the end, when I tried to make spatial selection to check if it worked, it returns me only 270 points over 1399. The problem is points seem to be correctly on lines when I zoom but spatial selection seem to select only those who are on the tip of lines but not just on the lines (what I want to know). So, I tried to make the same on PostgreSQL with this query:

```
SELECT P.id, P.geom
from eclairage_public.ligne L,eclairage_public.point P
WHERE ST_Intersects(P.geom, L.geom);
```

But it returns only 305 points.

I don't understand and I don't find a way to know which points are not on lines.
Also, I would like to find a way to automatically put on lines those which are not on lines. Is there a solution?

Thank you for anybody's help! :)

Comment: An intersection between points an lines is quite tough :) I believe that even a tiny discrepancy in the coordinates precision would be enough to make them disjoint. Could you elaborate a bit on your use case and add a data sample?

Comment: Yep most likely a rounding error. The points are probably as close to the lines as precision allows, but not actually on them

Comment: What I don't understand it's why points are not on them though I activate snapping to put them on lines. When I move some points until they snap a node on lines and I reselect them by location, it works for them. However, I need to know if they are on lines (not only on nodes) and which line and after that, how to automatically move those which aren't on the lines where I wanted to put on.

Comment: @Jérôme can you add some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: @Jérôme A point coordinate is exact. A location along a line is derived from the coordinates of the 2 adjacent nodes, and it could mean having an infinite number of decimals. When snapping to a node, the node has an exact coordinate too. There are two solutions for what you want to do: 1) don't select points intersecting the line but rather points that are near a line (let's say that are within 0.0001m) or 2) add nodes to the lines first, then snap your points to these new nodes.

Comment: Thank you! It's what I thought. So, in pgradmin, I created a buffer around lines in a view and now, I want to create a trigger. So, I add line name empty column in my points table and I try to create a trigger function to update line name column in point table with spatial intersection between the point geom and the buffer geom of lines in the view.

Comment: However, for now, I don't know exactly how to do it and I don't know if it's a good solution. My final goals are to check if points are on lines to get informations like knowing to which line corresponds a specific point or to count the number of points in a specific line. We do you think?

Comment: it's better to use `st_dwithin()` instead of a buffer, something like `select pt.id, ln.id from pointLayer pt left join lineLayer ln on st_dwithin(pt.geom,ln.geom,0.001)`. In a trigger, it becomes a bit more complex because the relation is affected by both point and line locations, so you would likely need 2 triggers. Don't forget to handle cases where a point or line is moved away, as well as point on line intersection (i.e. 2 found lines)